# SelectizeInput becomes opaque when disabled

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, bslib

I am developing a shiny app in which I use the `bslib` package for theming. However, when I disable the input as shown below it becomes unreadable:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fluid(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  theme = bs_theme(preset = "shiny"),
  selectizeInput("id1", "selection unreadable", choices = 1:3, multiple = T)  
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$id1, ignoreInit =T, {
    shinyjs::disable('id1')
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Is there a way I can still use `bs_theme(preset = "shiny")` but with a more transparent look for disabled inputs like with the default theme:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  selectInput("id1", "selection readable", choices = 1:3, multiple = T)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$id1, ignoreInit =T, {
    shinyjs::disable('id1')
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this should be reported as bug https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the CSS style of the items under the disabled status. Or you can use the `lock` method and define the CSS style of the items under the locked status (by default there's no particular CSS style for such items):

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

css <- "
.selectize-input.items.not-full.has-options.has-items.locked > .item {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}"

ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  theme = bs_theme(preset = "shiny"),
  selectizeInput("id1", "selection readable", choices = 1:3, multiple = TRUE)  
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$id1, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    shinyjs::runjs("$('#id1')[0].selectize.lock();")
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```